# Move and replace file in a loop problem showing is being used by another process problem

Tags: java, movefile

I'm creating every time a file  moving and replacing it from source folder to a destination folder with the same name
in a loop and this is the problem :

For the first move and replace, it works well then it yells the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. when replacing the file in the destination folder
and this is the method moving the file and replacing it every time

```
  public static void moveAndReplaceFile(String source, String destination) {
        try {
            Files.move(
                    Paths.get(source),
                    Paths.get(destination),
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Fail when moving and replacing");
        }
    }
```

can you help me guys? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If its a network storage that you are using, then this can happen. As a workaround, you can try adding a sleep of 60seconds before executing the Files.Move API.

Comment: 60 seconds will late all my process and i dont think it is a good idea thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add the ATOMIC_MOVE option if supported :

```
public static void moveAndReplaceFile(String source, String destination) {
    try {
        Files.move(
                Paths.get(source),
                Paths.get(destination),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, 
                StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Fail when moving and replacing");
    }
}
```

See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Comment: i did try it and now it telling me java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\folder1\folder\example.xlsx -> C:\folderexported\example.xlsx

Comment: And the user used by your app has the correct rights ?

Comment: it's in my local machine i have all the rights

Comment: see some clues here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988210/java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-while-using-files-move

Comment: i did follow the link and the comments delete and recreate the folder after the move,close the current folder ect ... but still the same prob access denied any way thank you my brother